# Chebyshev’s $\theta_1(x) = \sum_{n \leqslant x } (x-n) \Lambda_1 (n)$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, chebyshev-function

Let $\theta_1 = \int_{1}^{x}\theta (t)dt$, for $x \gt 1$ where $\theta(x)$ is the Chebyshev’s function.

Letting $\Lambda_1(n) = \log n,\;$ if $n$ is prime, then $\Lambda_1(n)=0.$ Otherwise prove that:

$$\theta_1(x) = \sum_{n \leqslant x } (x-n) \Lambda_1 (n).$$

Comment: First compute $\int_n^{n+1}\vartheta(t)dt$.

Comment: Guess I’d need help carrying that and building towards the proof

Comment: If $x$ is an integer then $\vartheta_1(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{x-1}\int_n^{n+1}\vartheta(t)dt$, if $x$ is not an integer, you have $\vartheta_1(x)=\vartheta_1(\lfloor x\rfloor)+\int_{\lfloor x\rfloor}^x \vartheta(t)dt$ and you can compute $\vartheta_1(\lfloor x\rfloor)$ using the case $x\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: $$\int_1^x \theta(t)dt=\int_1^x \sum_p 1_{p\le t}dt= \sum_p\int_1^x1_{p\le t}dt$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Method 1: Geometric interpretation

From single-variable calculus, integrals can be interpreted as area under the curve. To calculate the area under the step-function's "curve," we consider calculating them vertically. Since each rectangle has area $(x-n)\Lambda_1(n)$, we conclude

$$
\vartheta_1(x)=\sum_{n\le x}(x-n)\Lambda_1(n)
$$

### Method 2: Abel's summation (aka Riemann-Stieltjes integration)

Consider reversing Abel's summation:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\vartheta_1(x)
&=\int_1^x\vartheta(t)\mathrm dt
=t\vartheta(t)|_1^x-\int_1^x t\mathrm d\vartheta(t) \\
&=x\vartheta(x)-\sum_{1<n\le x}n\Lambda_1(n)
\end{aligned}
$$

Since $\Lambda_1(1)=0$, it does not make any difference if we change the summation interval to $1\le n\le x$. As a result, we get

$$
\vartheta_1(x)=x\sum_{n\le x}\Lambda_1(n)-\sum_{n\le x}n\Lambda_1(n)=\sum_{n\le x}(x-n)\Lambda_1(n)
$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\theta_1(x) = \int_1^x \theta(t) dt= \int_1^x \left(\sum_{n\le t} \Lambda_1(n) \right)  dt =\sum_{n\le x} \int_{n}^x \Lambda_1(n) dt = \sum_{n \le x}(x-n)\Lambda_1(n).$$